# Coldfusion Recursive Tree custom tag or UDF

Tags: recursion, coldfusion, tags

Ive been using the custom tag from megalingo called dbtree for my drop down menu's for my websites.

The issue i have is its rather clunky and not the easiest to modify if we need to design a menu to have a different structure. IE including divs for mega menus etc.

Im wondering if anyone knows of an efficient way to generate a recursive query that generates a <ul><li></li></ul> for a drop down menu.

Ideally id like to be able to pass in a query and have the ability to tweak the code so i can make all sorts of dropdown menus...

Any advice greatly appreciated

Comment: sounds like a good opportunity for you to create a useful open source project!

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches to this.

1. In SQL Server, you would need a Recursive CTE. There are lots of them. [recursive cte with ranking functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416512/recursive-cte-with-ranking-functions) . If you Google "Recursive CTE" you will find more.
2. The other is to do recursion via ColdFusion. Here is an example of that:
   [Recursive Function in Coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807871/recursive-function-in-coldfusion?rq=1)