# How would I pass an array to a template as an attribute and then use the array, then use the template recursively?

Tags: recursion, coldfusion, cfml

I've been working with ColdFusion CFML for a few months after using JSP for several years and there are still some things I'm having trouble figuring out in this language. Google, CFDocs, and Adobe have been no help with this particular question.

I'm building a feature to display comments below an article, where a comment can also have child comments. I have all the data imported and it looks great. I'm using a query that returns an array of structs, it gets each first-level comment for the article and I loop back through that array and attach an array of structs to each comment-struct that has children.

I've written a template to loop through and display the list of first-level comments but I'd like it to call itself recursively on each comment that has child comments until it has displayed all of the child comments of each comment. I'd assume that the best way to accomplish this would be for the template to call itself while passing it the array of child comments.

I've read several articles that explain how to create a `CFModule` but NONE that say how to actually use the attribute that you pass it. Here's one of the things I've tried:

(in the original template):

```
<h4>Comments</h4>
<div id="comments" name="comments">
  <cfmodule template="comments.cfm" comments="#Variables.page.comments#">
</div>
```

(in the template that I want to eventually call recursively):

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop array = "#comments#" index = "comment">
    <div>#comment.commenter_name# says</div>
    <div>#comment.created#</div>
    <div>#comment.content#</div>
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

I can't just use `Variables.page.comments` in the second template because the template's going to call itself recursively; for instance, I'll want the array at `Variables.page.comments[2].comments` the next time, `Variables.page.comments[2].comments[5].comments` the time after, etc

Comment: I don't think you want a `<cfmodule>` for this. You need a function, `.cfc`, a ColdFusion component. If you Google "coldfusion recursive function" you should see lots of examples. [Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3807871/1636917)

Comment: Well you probably want to use 'attributes.comments' as the reference to your array, inside the cfmodule template. But, if you want to do something recursively, you want to use a CFC method.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate your hierarchical view by wrapping your rendering logic around

```
<cfscript>
    cfsavecontent variable="html" {
       do logic stuff here
    }
    writeOutput(html);
<cfscript>
```

which will store your output into a variable. Then output the variable.

You could also write a recursive function to do it, and then simply output the returned string, like below. You might want to add some limit logic so you don't output the entire discussion at once, depending on how big the discussion are.

```
string function outputComments (
    required array comments) {
    var html = "";
    for (var comment in arguments.comments) {
        html &= "<li>#comment.message#";
        if (comment.children.length) {
            html &= outputComments(comment.children);
        }
        html &= "</li>";
    }
    if (html != "") {
        html = "<ul>#html#</ul>";
    }
    return html;
}

writeOutput(outputComments(comments));
```

Having done a bunch of this kind of work, you may want to consider rendering your comments/replies in some sort of JavaScript ajax-driven widget, using a service that returns comments data in JSON, where you get a page of comments or replies at a time. I wrote a Facebook-style comment widget that worked that way, and the advantage is that you don't have to worry about conversation size.